# Why doesn't this loop?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Why doesn't this code loop to return each character in product's string? It only returns the first and stops.

```
def fix_machine(debris, product):
    n = 0
    while debris.find(product[n]) != -1:
        return product[n]
        n = n + 1
```

Sorry about noob question

Comment: `return` breaks out of the loop

Comment: I have no idea what language this is in, but `return product[n]` would likely exit the defined method entirely.

Comment: it seems to be Python language... Is it? And yes, you should put your return out of the while loop by reducing its indentation and putting the n = n + 1 before return. Also, most likely you want to return n rather than product[n].

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes, this is Python. What I'm trying to do is for Python to print out product's string if all of it's characters can be found in debris. So basically, as long as it finds each in debris, I want it to print out the entire string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected. `return` will stop the execution of your function. You can print it instead if you want:

```
def fix_machine(debris, product):
    n = 0
    while debris.find(product[n]) != -1:
        print product[n]
        n = n + 1
```

Comment: Thanks, now I get another major difference between print and return.

Comment: No problem, happy to help. Feel free to accept an answer by clicking on the grey checkmark, if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `return`, the function is immediately terminated and the returned value is returned. If you want to return multiple values from a function, you can use `yield`. Also note that you should check whether `n` is still within `product`'s bounds.

```
def fix_machine(debris, product):
    n = 0
    while n < len(product) and debris.find(product[n]) != -1:
        yield product[n]
        n = n + 1
```

This makes it a generator function. You can loop the entries, or collect them in a list:

```
for d in fix_machine("some characters", "some different characters"):
    print(d)

print(list(fix_machine("some characters", "some different characters")))
```

Output would be e.g. `['s', 'o', 'm', 'e', ' ']`

---

If, as by you comment, you want to "print product if all of it's characters can be found in debris", you can try this:

```
def fix_machine(debris, product):
    if all(c in debris for c in product):
        print(product)
```

Comment: Thanks, tobias. I was actually trying to get it to print product if all of it's characters can be found in debris.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the syntax in python, but `return` in languages I am familiar with typically leave the block to return to the method calling block.

What you want is something like:

```
method
    while true
        build array
    end while
    return array
end method
```

Comment: How would I end while in my case?